# Difference in behaviour for Unicode characters in shell

Tags: unicode, zsh

- OS: `MacOS`
- Shell: `zsh`
- Locale: `LC_ALL` and `LANG` set to `en_US.UTF-8`
- (Unicode Code Point: `U+1F4A1`, UTF-8 Encoding: `0xF0 0x9F 0x92 0xA1`)

I noticed some inconsistent behaviour when printing an emoji from a Go program, i.e.,

Suppose I am printing  from my program to standard output (stdout), it gets printed fine.
Also, pasting the same on my terminal works perfectly because `locale` is configured correctly — UTF8.

Now, suppose if I have set `LC_ALL` and `LANG` to `en_US.US-ASCII`, then pasting the emoji on my terminal results in:

```
�<009f><0092>�
```

but the emoji printed from the Go program to standard output is still working fine.

But why? I expected the output of the program to be gibberish as well because of the difference in encodings set.

Comment: You aren't pasting the Unicode code point; you are pasting the encoding. If you switch the locale to ASCII and try something like `print "\U0001f4a1"`, you'll get an error rather than any bytes at all.

Comment: I suspect your Go code is *starting* with the code point, and is simply assuming UTF-8 if the given locale isn't suitable (which seems a bit broken, but I don't know exactly what it is doing).

Comment: @shmsr : Why do you set LANG to en_US.US-ASCII? The character you are going to print, is not contained in the ASCII character set, so you have undefined behaviour.

Comment: @user1934428 Yes, I wanted to see it broken. But when it didn't break, I was shocked and posted a question here. That's it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting LC_ALL and LANG *informs* programs *how to show things*, i.e., what you expect *them* to send to your terminal emulator, and what you expect to send them *from* your terminal emulator.  It does not change how `Terminal` or `iTerm2` or whatever terminal emulator you may be using actually displays things, nor how it actually sends things.

That is, by setting LC_ALL and LANG to en_US.US-ASCII, you've lied to several programs about how your terminal emulator works.  Go ignored the lie, while zsh believed it and started behaving weirdly.  (Go ignored these deliberately since there's basically nothing else to do anyway.  It's not clear precisely why zsh believed the lie and started changing behavior here, although there's probably some sort of history with meta keys at play.)

Comment: Ah, okay. I tried playing the character encoding for terminal emulation for iTerm and yes output from the program also breaks now. Thanks for explaining, @torek!